# Watson Conversation Intent Analytics

Tags: watson-conversation

I see that in the Watson Conversation tooling, we can see the usage activity broken down by Conversation intents. Is there a way to access this intent usage data via the Conversation API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Watson Conversation service has an API](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/) to access and modify the workspace, its components and to obtain the logs. The [REST function to retrieve (list) the logs](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/#logs) has parameters to pass in some filters.

I wrote a [Python-based tool](https://github.com/data-henrik/watson-conversation-tool/) a while ago that exploits most of the API and demonstrates its usage. It supports log retrieval. Note that the duration for which logs are available depends on the usage plan.

Answer (score 1):

You need to access the [call](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/conversation-simple/blob/master/app.js#L56) for the conversation message and get the intent with the return, [something](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/conversation-simple/blob/master/app.js#L70) like: `response.intents.intent`

Like @data_henrik said, the conversation tool can use the getLogs method for access **all** return, `intents`, `entities`, `context` variables, `input` from the user and your bot, etc.

See the Official [reference](https://console.bluemix.net/docs/services/conversation/expression-language.html#accessing-and-evaluating-objects) here.